# Select first row in tableview at default and fire didselect when load view

Tags: ios

When the view is load, the tableview will select the first row and it fire the didselectatrow method to do something.
I've just know how to select the first row but it not fire the didselectatrow method at a same time
Show me how to do like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just call the method manually in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // select the first row
    NSIndexPath *firstRowPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:firstRowPath animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:firstRowPath];
}
```